# When do you use code blocks?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, codeblocks, curly-braces

When do you use code blocks in C/C++/C#, etc.? I know the theoretical reason behind them, but when do you use them in real programs?

**EDIT**: I have just realised that I use them in `switch` statements, where variables would otherwise be in the same scope (grr for things like `i`):

```
switch (x) { case "abc": { /* code */ } break; }
```

etc
(Just to clarify, in a switch statement, the extra braces are *NOT* required.)

---

Related:

- [Do you use curly braces for additional scoping? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249009/do-you-use-curly-braces-for-additional-scoping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249009/do-you-use-curly-braces-for-additional-scoping)

Answer (score 10):

I sometimes, but rarely, use naked code blocks to limit scope.  For example, take the following code:

```
double bedroomTemperature = ReadTemperature(Room.Bedroom);
database.Store(Room.Bedroom, bedroomTemperature);

double bathroomTemperature = ReadTemperature(Room.Bathroom);
database.Store(Room.Bedroom, bedroomTemperature);
```

The code looks fine at first glance, but contains a subtle copy-pasta error.  In the database we have stored the bedroom temperature for both readings.  If it had been written as:

```
{
    double bedroomTemperature = ReadTemperature(Room.Bedroom);
    database.Store(Room.Bedroom, bedroomTemperature);
}

{
    double bathroomTemperature = ReadTemperature(Room.Bathroom);
    database.Store(Room.Bedroom, bedroomTemperature);
}
```

Then the compiler (or even IDE if it is intelligent enough) would have spotted this.

However, 90% of the time the code can be refactored to make the naked blocks unnecessary, e.g. the above code would be better written as a loop or two calls to a method that reads and stores the temperature:

```
foreach (Room room in [] { Room.Bedroom, Room.Bathroom })
{
    double temperature = ReadTemperature(room);
    database.Store(room, temperature);
}
```

Naked blocks are useful on occasion though.

Answer (score 3):

I do the same thing with switch blocks, even though it isn't required. In general, I use code blocks where they either make code more readable (whether that's through giving similar blocks of code a similar appearance or just getting the indenting) or they properly scope variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `finally` like behavior in C++ by using code blocks and RAII objects.

```
{
   std::fstream f(filename)
   ...
}
```

will release the file descriptor in the destructor no matter what causes us to leave the block.

(Personally, I'm still trying to make a practice of this. My c roots hold a death grip on my habits...)

Comment: You can also use this: Make a wrapper object around a synchronization primitive and put that on a stack in the block you need protected. This way you can't forget to release the lock.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the obvious ("when required by syntax", like in a switch or a try catch finally),
Whenever you need to treat a block of 2 or more statements as an atomic unit