# Why is ;; allowed after a local variable declaration, but not after a field declaration?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I saw this weird behaviour and I wonder if there's a reasonable explanation for this:

When I put by ( by accident) an additional/extra semicolon in a function's local variable like:

```
public void MyMethod ()
{
    int a = 1;;
    Console.WriteLine(a); //dummy 
}
```

It does compile but it shows that it's redundant.

[image]

But when I did that with fields (also by accident) ,  I got an error (compilation) :

[image]

**Question**

Is there any reason for this restrictiveness in fields ?

<sup>Nb I already know the other restrictiveness thing for not allowing `var` with fields. But here it's something different.</sup>

Comment: How do you produce these beautiful screen-dump-patches?

Comment: C# support empty statements so ; on its own is valid within a method body, but you can't have statements in the body of a class so ; is not valid there.

Comment: @DrKoch [here](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm)

Comment: "beautiful"? When did straight arrows become more beautiful than good old freehand circles? At least they are red. +1 for drop shadow.

Comment: @kapep Circles accuracy ( especially with code) can hide other stuff where an arrow is 100% precise without disturbing . also an arrow can provide "source" to "destination" ( just like my "Exception" to `;` arrow). there are places where a circle fits. this is not one of them :-) ( my opinion) - Example here http://i.imgur.com/UpklA5G.png , it hurts my eyes and prevents from reading it as a whole fluent line.

Comment: @RoyiNamir This "source" to "destination" thing is a compelling argument. You could add a circle around the arrow to improve it even more! But anyway, it's more about the [free hand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/168146) part than about the circle: http://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Y9I.png see the beauty?

Comment: @kapep Sorry I can't see the beauty. it looks like a 4 years old draw a circle. besides — the "beautiful" word is regarding the whole package : torn edges , shadows etc. _not_ just circle or arrow. but we can't have everybody happy. can't we ? :-) not to mention that you took my print screen and added the circle. so you really should compare myne to yours which is http://i.imgur.com/HBm7jHq.png . and here - there's no doubt.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`;` alone is a statement (empty statement), but only *declaration* statements are allowed in the body of a class; other kinds of statement can only appear in the body of a method.

Comment: so declaration is not a statement ? everything that ends with `;` is a statement.

Comment: @Selman22 Declaration is a statement. an empty statement by itself is not a declaration statement.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov this answer says _statements are not allowed in the body of a class._ and if declaration is a statement then this is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Selman22: A field declaration is not a statement.  A local variable declaration is a statement.  Nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 26):

`;` itself is an empty statement. And in class scope only the declaration statements are allowed.The class body is defined in `C# Specification 5.0, §10.1.6 Class Body`

```
class-body:
{   class-member-declarations   }
```

For example you can't initialize a field in a separate statement:

```
class Foo 
{
    int x = 2; // this is allowed 
    x = 5; // this is not
}
```

So you can only declare fields and other members but you can't use other statements in a class body.

Comment: I was about to comment on the accepted answer asking for the source (grammar). Thanks, +1!

Answer (score 6):

It is not part of local variable declaration, it's a statement by itself, as indicated by Thomas.

This is valid:

```
public void MyMethod ()
{
    ;;;
    int a = 1;


    ;
    Console.WriteLine(a); //dummy 
    ;;
}
```

The idea of semi-colon statement is to allow such constructs:

```
while(mycondition) ;
```

It does not make sense to allow it in in the body of class, it brings no extra value.

TLDR; this has nothing to do with variable/field declaration

You might want to take a look at this thread too: [When do you use scope without a statement in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458124/when-do-you-use-scope-without-a-statement-in-c/27458354#27458354)

It is kind of similiar, but not completely, it will help you to understand why

`int a = 1;;;`

is valid.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case the compiler sees a no-op statement. It doesn't matter that the second `;` comes after a variable declaration.

In the second case the compiler sees an attempt to create an empty declaration which isn't allowed.

Answer (score -4):

Inside the body of a function the redundant ; is an empty statement but in the class declaration is an undeclared field and it not allowed.

Comment: Why would you post a new answer to a question that's already been answered, especially when your answer is wrong and less informative than the others?