# Are there any benefits to using curly braces for just a block of code (without using for, if, try etc)?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use curly braces for additional scoping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249009/do-you-use-curly-braces-for-additional-scoping)
>   [Floating curly braces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246755/floating-curly-braces-in-c-sharp)

By accident I spotted the following in C#:

```
if(condition) return true;
{
  // perform this if true
}
```

When investigating, I realised that you can simply apply curly braces to blocks of code, which made me think it would be akin to 'scoping' the code:

```
{
  string foo = "foo";
}

string foo = "new foo!";
```

...but it doesn't.

Are there any benefits, features or uses of why you would want to do this?

Comment: Apologies, missed this - just spotted this has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246755/floating-curly-braces-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ...but it doesn't.

Actually, it does. The reason that you get a compiler error on the code

```
{
    string foo = "foo";
}

string foo = "new foo!";
```

is because local variables are in scope throughout the **entire** block in which the declaration occurs. Therefore, the "second" declaration of `foo` is in scope in the whole block, including "above" where it is declared, and therefore it conflicts with the "first" `foo` declared in the inner scope.

You could do this:

```
{
    string foo = "foo";
}

{
    string foo = "new foo!";
}
```

Now, the two scopes do not overlap and you do not get the compiler error that you are implicitly referring to in saying "...but it doesn't."

> Are there any benefits, features or uses of why you would want to do this?

It lets you use the same simple name in two different blocks of code. I think this is in general a very bad idea, but that is what this feature lets you do.

Comment: +1 for it generally being a bad idea, if you find yourself needing to do this you should take a step back and reevaluate your code.

Comment: Trust me, I think it's horrible but was surprised when it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It does add an additional scope to the code, such that the following *is* legal.

```
{
    string foo = "foo";
}

{
    string foo = "foo2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does scope that code.  You can do this:

```
{
  string foo = "foo";
}

if (someCondition)
{
  string foo = "new foo!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is scoping the code.  The problem with your experiment is that the outer scope conflicts with the inner scope.  Consider:

```
public void ScopedFoo {
    {
      string foo = "foo";
    }
    {
      string foo = "bar";
    }
}
```