# Curly brackets in JSP code

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page I am working on and I am confused by some of the formatting/coding.

There are sections where it's obvious what's going on:

```
<%
        if (.....)
        {
%>
      <input type=hidden name="blahblah" value="moreblah">
<%
        }
%>
```

But now I see sections where I have no idea how or why it works/compiles:

```
<%
    {
        // do stuff here
        String sClass = "blahblah"
        if ( sClass.equals("") )
        {
            sClass = "blah";
        }
    }
%>
```

There's no if or while or for or anything at the start of those curly brackets. Why does that compile and produce a good jsp page?

Comment: Mark's answer has it.

I would recommend you to read Kathy Sierra's Head First JSP & servlets: it helps a lot understanding the inner workins of a JSP page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're scope limiting, as per normal Java behavior, as in this [other/similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241088/what-do-curly-braces-by-themselves-mean-in-java).

In essence they define a block, and sClass is only available in that particular block.

Comment: Is this a good thing to be doing? I am trying to bring this code up to date and had never seen this before.

Comment: Well that depends -- if you want to ensure that `sClass` is only used within the scope of the braces then it can be helpful, but it's certainly not required.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you NOT learn how to write scriptlets in JSPs.  They're ugly at best and unmaintainable at worst.

A better strategy is to learn [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/) and keep scriptlets out of your pages.  I think Hans Bergsten's JSP book from O'Reilly is the best there is.  Read that, and don't write scriptlet code.  You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 2):

i believe like other languages curly braces are just a way of telling the compiler/code interpreter that you have sectioned off multiple lines into a particular scope.  Scope meaning the area that the current running code has access to variables, functions, and other resources declared inside the current "scope".

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about that. Writing raw Java code in a JSP file is considered [*bad practice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831238/jsp-for-business-layer/1832327#1832327). Replace that (sorry for the word) *nasty* stuff by [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) and [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). The [`core`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) taglib supports pretty much of all what you need.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 

<c:if test="${ ... }">
    <input type=hidden name="blahblah" value="moreblah">
</c:if>

<c:set var="sClass" value="blahblah" />
<c:set var="sClass" value="${sClass == '' ? 'blah' : sClass}" />
```

Although the last example doesn't make any sense, but this should give you **the** picture.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put any keywords like `if`, `for`, `while` etc before beginning of any code block. Whatever variables you define in the block will be visible only in that block.