# Why there is no compile time error? Strange - Java

Tags: java, coding-style, syntax, if-statement

I had an if statement checking some value, And encountered a weird bug(Not sure!). My code was incorrect syntactically and in result it produced a wrong result, however eclipse didn't raised any error while compiling. Why My below code worked?

```
if((this.trackPointList.get(point).getTurnOutId().equals(seg.getSegRef().getTurnOut())) && seg.getSegRef().getKind().equals("arc")); // <---- See here I have semicolon
    {
       ... code to run ...
    }
```

Above code check only first condition and ignores `seg.getSegRef().getKind().equals("arc")` but I guess this should raised an issue at compile time, Am I right? My logic worked once I debugged it by skimming line by line and found this semicolon. I will appreciate if someone could explain, if it is a valid syntax.

Enlighten Me, Please!

Comment: IntelliJ will give you a warning right away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `;` makes Java think that the body of the `if` conditional is complete, even if there is no other code preceding it. In effect, the code in the `if` statement is executed, but no body exists because the `;` is there.

The `{ ...code to run...}` is just a code block that executes, and anything declared inside that block is not visible outside the block. It will always run here because it's not part of the `if` block.

edit: here's another stack overflow question about the `{ }` blocks: [What do curly braces in Java mean by themselves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241088/what-do-curly-braces-by-themselves-mean-in-java)

Comment: Now this makes sense :), I thought it is syntactically incorrect Thank you stacks(I like stack instead of heaps ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The code is syntactically correct. You can write ifs without braces, like:

```
if(condition) statement;
```

Having empty statements is also valid. For instance this code is valid:

```
int a = 0;;
;;;
```

So an empty if is valid as well, although it doesn't make much sense :)

```
if(condition);
```

Answer (score 2):

An if statement followed by a semicolon is called an "empty if statement".
It rarely is of any use, but it's syntactically legal.

You can write something like this

```
if ( doSomethingThatReturnsABoolean() )
   ;  // Empty statement
else
   doSomeOtherThing()
```

but it would be better to write

```
if ( !doSomethingThatReturnsABoolean() )
   doSomeOtherThing()
```

Regarding your observation that only the first condition gets checked:
If the first condition returns `false` the second condition will not get checked, because

```
(false && secondCondition)
```

always equals to false, so the value of secondCondition is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The `;` after the `if(..)` statement represents an empty statement that is executed conditionally when the `if(..)` evaluates to true. The `{ .. }` represents a code block that always executes with it's own scope.

The second condition may be ignored if the first condition is false due to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

`if(condition);` is equivalent to `if(condition){}`

same thing with `for loop` & `while loop`:

`for(;condition;);` is equivalent to `for(;condition;){}`

`while(condition);` is equivalent to `while(condition){}`