# For Loop ending after 1 rotation when using Scanner

Tags: java, for-loop, input, java.util.scanner

I am currently working on a program that examines each line in a text document, and does the same modifications to it. However, the for loop is only looping through once rather than the needed 5 times. Below is the portion of the code that is not working.

```
//I think this part is correct but I decided to include it just in case.
Scanner infile = null;
try {
    infile = new Scanner(new File("solution.txt"));
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    System.exit(0);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
{
    s = infile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("LOOP"); //Just a debug test
}
infile.close();
```

The output of this code is the following:

```
define 88 as INT
LOOP
```

Whereas it should be:

```
define 88 as INT
LOOP
define 89 as INT
LOOP
define 90 as INT
LOOP
define 91 as INT
LOOP
define 92 as INT
LOOP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

The code after [is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241088/1290264) by itself, and so runs separately once.

```
{
    s = infile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("LOOP"); //Test system out
}
```

Comment: @Ripread Please accept the answer if you think that solved your problem.

Comment: Don't worry, I will. Still need to wait 5 min though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **;** at the end of for-loop.

The for-loop code you used

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
    {
        s = infile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("LOOP"); //Test system out
    }
```

is equal to the following code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    }
    s = infile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("LOOP"); // Test system out
```

That's why only the first one line content is read from the plain text file.

You'd better use  **infile.hasNext()** to check if there is any content. Then read it. like

```
    while (infile.hasNext()) {
        s = infile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("LOOP"); // Test system out
    }
```