# Return Values from methods

Tags: java, swing

I need help to figure out what i'm missing. I've gone though the code and I don't understand why I am getting this error. I new to java and mistakes do tend to happen when learning the syntax please help me fix this return from method.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestScores {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  int[] testScores;
  testScores = getTestScores();
  getAverage(testScores);
  double average;


  average = getAverage(); //*method getAverage in class TestScores cannot be
                            *applied to given types;
                            *required: int[]
                            *found: no arguments
                            *reason: actual and formal argument lists differ                     
                            */in length

  displayScores(average);

  System.out.println(testScores[0]);
  System.out.println(testScores[1]);
  System.out.println(testScores[2]);
}
        public static int[] getTestScores()
            {
    int[] scores = new int[3];


        for (int testValues = 0; testValues < scores.length; testValues++)
            {
                String input;

                input =
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the test score for number " + (testValues + 1) + " ? ");


                while (input.isEmpty())
                {
                    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nothing was enterd for test " + (testValues + 1) + " please enter a value.");
                }

                        scores[testValues] = Integer.parseInt(input);


                while (scores[testValues] <= 0 || scores[testValues] > 100)
                    {
                        input =
                                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("The number " + scores[testValues] + " for test " + (testValues + 1) + " is invalid."
                                                            + " Please enter a number in the range of 1 though 100");

                        scores[testValues] = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    }
    }

    return scores;

}

        public static int[] getAverage(int[] input)
        {
            for (int avg = 0; avg < input.length; avg++)
            {
                int total;
                double result;

                total = input[avg];
                result = total / input.length;
            }
            return result; //cannot find symbol
                             *symbol:   variable result
                             */location: class TestScores
        }

        public static void displayScores(double average)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The average is " + average + ".");

            if (average <= 100 || average >= 90)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The letter grade is A.");                   
            }
            else if (average < 90 || average <= 80)
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The letter grade is B.");
            }
            else if (average < 80 || average <= 70)
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The letter grade is C.");
            }
            else if (average < 70 || average <= 60)
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The letter grade is D.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error are you currently getting?

Comment: as per the signature you need to pass an array as an argument to getAverage method . change this line 


  average = getAverage();     to average = getAverage(testScores);

Comment: i made a comment of the error im getting from viewing the code next to the values

Comment: Changed the line and i got this error "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to double"

Comment: @Daimeon Do not post so much code to Stack Overflow. [Strip it down to the bare minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your issue. In doing so, you would likely have solved your problem. Rewriting a minimal case is a good debugging technique, FYI.

Comment: then you have to use int, don't use double. otherwise you will need to parse it into double. your variable average must be int too not double.

Comment: @BasilBourque i didnt know if my code from other classes might have caused this problem.

Comment: @Daimeon Which is why you should write your code slowly, step by step, getting one little thing at a time to work. Compile & run often.

Comment: @BasilBourque: exactly as I stated in a comment to your answer.

Comment: @Satya you helped and now the code had compiled correctly i see the issue and fix it Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Out of scope

```
{
   double result;
   …
}
return result; //cannot find symbol
```

You define the variable inside the curly braces. Those braces define a block of code. That block has [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). After the closing curly brace, any variables defined within are gone (all references dropped, become candidates for [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))). When you say `return result`, **there is no `result`**.

Move that definition *outside* the braces.

```
double result;
{
   result = …
   …
}
return result; //cannot find symbol
```

See: [*Java, What do curly braces mean by themselves?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241088/642706)

Comment: Just did and now im getting a error from the variable result might not have been initialized

Comment: Is that an error or a warning? A warning I suspect. You can set a default value for the variable. Or tell your IDE to ignore that rule. `double result = 0;`

Comment: @Daimeon: then you're not creating code correctly. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Free association code writing and throwing junk at the wall to see what sticks won't work. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Comment: I am currently using NetBeams and i'm writing the code by methods most of the time just came into this warring and getting frustrated i don't know why

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your help i fixed it. I learned from this mistake.

Comment: @Daimeon Slow down. Google is your friend. Do your coding with a classmate; see [Pair Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming). Please search Stack Overflow before posting, your Netbeans messages have already been covered. Do not conflate a compiler error with a compiler warning; warnings may or may not be valid, depending on your context.

Comment: @BasilBourque don't have classmates and there is so much to run though in Google. Thank you and sorry for my mistake on what kinds of error i was getting.